# How can i fix this react-routing-dom error?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, frontend, react-router-dom

i have a problem with the routing of my application
where i get this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7cM8c.png)

I don't know what causes this problem

I also added a github repo Link, for those that wanted to check out the Application.
[Link To Github Repo](https://github.com/G-HK/errors/tree/main/Routing-error)

## App.js

```
import React, { Component, useEffect } from "react";
import './App.css';

import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

import NavBar from './components/NavBar';
import Home from './components/Home';
import ListPage from './components/ListPage';
import About from './components/About';
import Contact from './components/Contact';
import NotFound from './components/NotFound';

import Page from './components/Page';

import * as Pages from './components/Pages';

// test
import Page1 from './components/Pages/Page1';



function App() {



  useEffect(() => {

    let test = Object.values(Pages).map((page, index) =>

      // <Route key={index} path={"/" + page.name} element={page.name} />
      console.log(":" + page.name)

    )

    // Pages.Array.forEach((page, index) => {
    //   console.log(page);
    // })

    console.log(test);



  });

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />

          <Route path="/Listpage" exact element={<ListPage />} />


          <Route path="/Page" element={<Page />} >
            {/* <Route path=":Page1" exact element={<Page1 />} />  this one works */}
            {
              Object.values(Pages).map((page, index) =>
                <Route key={index} path={`:${page.name}`} exact element={<page.name />} />
              )
            }
          </Route>
          <Route path="/About" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/Contact" element={<Contact />} />
          <Route path="/*" element={<NotFound />} />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

## 'index.js'  from components folder

```
export { default as Page1 } from './Page1';
export { default as Page2 } from './Page2';
```

## Listpage.js

```
import React, { useEffect }from 'react';
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";


function ListPage() {


  useEffect(() => {

  

    console.log();
});

return (
         <div>
              <Link to="/Page/Page1"> Page1  </Link> 
              <Link to="/Page/Page2"> Page2  </Link>    
          </div>
        );
    
}


export default ListPage
```

*This is my folder structuur*
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XpxZ.png)